# ScrollView not smooth scroll

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, scrollview, smoothing

Why do not scroll smoothly? Very slowly scrolls.

Where is the mistake? 7 images.

**content_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/russia"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
......................................................
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```